# Awarding points with Rules for uploading a user picture

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

Does anyone know how to create a rule that awards points to a user for uploading an image?

Comment: The currently accepted answer doesn't seem like a real answer to me (obvious that you use userpoints module to ... award "points". Would you mind providing some more details about how that "uploading an image" is implemented? My wild guess = you have some content type, with an image field. If my guess is correct, is it reasonable to assume that that field gets "updated" as part of such uploading (eg with the filename of the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the "User Points" (https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module. 
It has rules integration (among many other modules) so this may be the one you're looking for. It also provides a hook API by the looks of it, so if you need more custom functionality than what it offers by default, you should be able to perform actions from within a custom module.